# Logstash cause the data loss

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I use the Logstash to process my web logs, but I find a problem about the data loss.

Now I have the 100 lines logs. I get the result which is less than 100 lines in sometimes after processing via Logstash. The weird thing is it doesn't display any error message.

The following code is my config of Logstash:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/home/jhowliu/Work/Log/201506/testing.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}

filter {
    csv {
        columns => ["ip", "time", "request", "status", "refer", "browser"]
    }

    grok {
        match => {
            "time" => "%{MONTHDAY:day}/%{MONTH:month}/%{YEAR:year}:%{TIME:time}"
        }
        overwrite => ["time"]
    }

    mutate {
        replace => {"time" =>"%{day}-%{month}-%{year} %{time}" }
    }

    if [request] != "-" {
        grok {
            match => {
                "request" => "%{URIPATH:dest_path}"
            }
        }
    }

    if [refer] != "-" {
        grok {
            match => {
                "refer" => "%{URIHOST}%{URIPATH:source_path}"
            }
        }
    }
}

output { 
    csv {
        fields => ["time", "ip", "dest_path", "source_path", "status"]
        path => "/home/jhowliu/testing.log"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there anything interesting about the lines that don't get processed?  Have you tried turning up debugging?

Comment: Hi, Alain, I have checked this kind of problem, I thought it wasn't the some lines that didn't get processed. Because I used the same log files, sometimes I got 100 lines, sometimes I got less than 100 lines. I will try this progress under the debugging.